# Problem embedding font and displaying it correctly in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, fonts, antialiasing

I'm looking for the right textfield parameters or work-around for my latest problem here dealing with Flash fonts & text fields.

I have a textFormat and textField generation some text using the Font: Franklin Gothic Book point size 8. Currently this is how the font will look when I run the movie:

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2503/4028956835_98cfbcb457_o.png))</sub>

The bottom ®MYLOGO is a jpg from Photoshop, clean and how it should look. Next up is the font directly typed on the stage in Flash, and the very top ®MYLOGO is generated from my code.

What parameters am I missing to make the code generated copy look as close as possible to the Jpeg?

My Code below:

```
var tsFont = new TextFormat();
    tsFont.font = FranklinGothic;
    tsFont.size = 8;
    tsFont.color = 0xFFFFFF;
    tsFont.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;

var tsLogo:TextField = new TextField();
    tsLogo.defaultTextFormat = tsFont;
    tsLogo.selectable = false;
    tsLogo.mouseEnabled = false;
    tsLogo.x = 18;
    tsLogo.y = 98;
    tsLogo.width = 64;
    tsLogo.height = 16;
    tsLogo.text = "®MYLOGO";

    addChild(tsLogo);
```

You guys may remember this code from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589495/access-of-undefined-property-for-timeline-addchild-code) X_x

---

**FIXED WORKING CORE:** thx to [Andy Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160372/andy-li)

```
var tsFont = new TextFormat();
    tsFont.font = (new FranklinGothic() as Font).fontName;
    tsFont.size = 8;
    tsFont.color = 0xFFFFFF;
    tsFont.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;

var tsLogo:TextField = new TextField();
    tsLogo.selectable        = false;
    tsLogo.mouseEnabled      = false;
    tsLogo.embedFonts        = true;
    tsLogo.antiAliasType     = flash.text.AntiAliasType.NORMAL;
    tsLogo.gridFitType       = "pixel";
    tsLogo.sharpness         = 400
    tsLogo.x                 = 6;
    tsLogo.y                 = 5;
    tsLogo.width             = 600;
    tsLogo.height            = 40;
    tsLogo.text              = "®MYLOGO";
    tsLogo.setTextFormat(tsFont)
```

Graphic Examples:

NORMAL

[image]

ADVANCED

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controlling text rendering in Flash is painful sometime...

You need to play around several properties: `antiAliasType`, `gridFitType`, `sharpness`, `thickness` of the `TextField`. Try [Adobe's example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts/#section5). Or a [even more detailed tutorial](http://www.peachpit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=flash&seqNum=336).

Comment: hey thx will be trying these out as well.. but just noticed something I increased my font size to 12 and 16 and I can tell it's not Franklin Gothic, but times and it looks much better at a size other then 8 hmm

Comment: Are you sure you embedded and using the embedded font?

Comment: I imported the font and gave it the class name: FranklinGothic, but I guess that's not all I have to do to embed it correct? :(

Comment: Try this: Change the line `tsFont.font = FranklinGothic;` to `tsFont.font = (new FranklinGothic() as Font).fontName;`. And then add `tsLogo.embedFonts = true;`.

Comment: Ah sweet that worked! My font's now FranklinGothic and the Aliasing works on it :D...

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this code:

tsLogo.antiAliasType = flash.text.AntiAliasType.NORMAL;

or

tsLogo.antiAliasType = flash.text.AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

Comment: hmm just tried both, still same result... starting to wonder if its something to do with the actual font Franklin Gothic

Comment: I just realized I have a different problem, emebedding fonts correctly, but your solutions does work for anti aliasing, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes make sure you check the Aliasing, but if that doesn't do it I would try calling:

```
tsLogo.setTextFormat(tsFont)
```

Right after you set the text.  That function will apply the font to the text in the field.